# Why do I get "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" when using `match` in Python?

Tags: python

I tried to run a Python script using

```
python3 ds_main.py
```

but it returns the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ds_main.py", line 14 in <module>
    import cmd_main
  File "/home/me/discord/cmd_main.py", line 190
    match action:
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

In this section, I did add a `match case` clause, which the error seems to be pointing to.

I checked the version using `python3 --version` which returns `Python 3.8.10`.

Comment: Could you share more of the code so that we can try to debug or reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python 3.8.10 does not support structural pattern matching (`match` keyword).

You need **Python ≥ 3.10**:

https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html

> [PEP 634](https://peps.python.org/pep-0634/), Structural Pattern Matching: Specification

Answer (score 1):

If you need to stay compatible with older Python versions (because of not up to date production operating system), then you shall use the old Python switch case fashion with a dictionary, as example:

```py
http_code = "418"

http_code_str = {
    "200": "OK",
    "404": "Not Found",
    "418": "I'm a teapot",
}
print(http_code_str.get(http_code, "Code not found"))
```